# Get response after submitted

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I have the CI controller to submit data using json, my plan is the display a submitted data in the response message, here the code for my controller:

```
            public function add_post()
    {
        $this->is_allowed('api_tbl_driver_task_add', false);

        $id = $this->get('task_id');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_id', 'Customer Id', 'trim|required|max_length[14]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('task_description', 'Task Description', 'trim|required|max_length[255]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('trans_type', 'Trans Type', 'trim|required|max_length[255]|in_list[installation]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('contact_number', 'Contact Number', 'trim|required|max_length[50]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer_name', 'Customer Name', 'trim|required|max_length[255]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('imei', 'Imei', 'trim|required|max_length[11]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {

            $save_data = [
                'customer_id' => $this->input->post('customer_id'),
                'task_description' => $this->input->post('task_description'),
                'trans_type' => $this->input->post('trans_type'),
                'contact_number' => $this->input->post('contact_number'),
                'customer_name' => $this->input->post('customer_name'),
                'imei' => $this->input->post('imei'),
                //'task_token' =>$this->setToken(sha1(rand(11111, 99999));,
            ];

            $save_tbl_driver_task = $this->model_api_tbl_driver_task->store($save_data);

            if ($save_tbl_driver_task) {
                $this->response([
                    'status'    => true,
                    'message'   => 'Data saved',
                    //'task_id'     => true,
                    'task_id'       = $this->get($id, true),
   //'task_id' =>     print_r($this->input->post('name'),

                ], API::HTTP_OK);
```

i want to print the task_id in the json response next to message. tried using `'task_id'        => json_decode($this->get($id)),` but no luck

big thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Check to see if `$id` is available in the scope and that it is a valid value.

Comment: What does `$this->get($id)` return? JSON? Pls, show function 'get' result.

Comment: Hi @ocBierman yes is available under loop function.

Comment: @Elena Vasilenko it return null :(

Comment: @Bireon what your function `$this->get($id)` do? Show its code.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot to take a look, I updated my question including the function

Comment: Hi , is there any wrong on my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the code is worked with return of value. Problem Solved!